# Update multiple Excel sheets of one document within one Pentaho Kettle transformation

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I am researching standard sample from Pentaho DI package: `GetXMLData - Read parent children rows`. It reads separately from same XML input `parent` rows & `children` rows. I need to do the same and update two different sheets of the same MS Excel Documents.

[image: GetXMLData - Read parent children rows sample]

My understanding is that normal way to achieve it is to put first sequence in one transformation file with XML Output or Writer, second to the second one & at the end create job with chain from start, through 1st & 2nd transformations.

My problems are:

- When I try to chain above sequences I loose content of first updated Excel sheet in the final document;
- I need to have at the end just one file with either Job or Transformation without dependencies (In case of above proposed scenario I would have 1 `KJB` job + 2 `KTR` transformation files).

Questions are:

- Is it possible to join 2 sequences from above sample with some `wait` node before starting update 2nd Excel sheet?
- If above doesn't work: Is it possible to embed transformations to the job instead of referencing them from external files?
- And extra question: What is better to use: Excel Output or Excel Writer?

=================

**UPDATE**:

Based on @AlainD proposal I have tried to put `Block` node in-between. Here is a result:

Looks like `Block` step can be an option, but somehow it doesn't work as expected with `Excel Output / Writers` node (or I do something wrong). What I have observed is that Pentaho tries to execute next after `Block` steps before Excel file is closed properly by the previous step. That leads to one of the following: I either get Excel file with one empty sheet or generated result file is malformed.

My input XML file (from Pentaho distribution) & test playground transformation are: [HERE](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_KxHXLmguIE9ofnYT6aOsy926o7HhbhS?usp=sharing)

NOTE: While playing do not forget to remove generated MS Excel files between runs.

Screenshot: 
[image: Playground]

Any suggestions how to fix my transformation?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Read one XML and write two Excel sheets? Read multiple Excel sheets from on xlsx? Write multiple Excel sheets in one xlsx? Please clarify before to read my tentative answer.

Comment: Hi @AlainD. Yes I want to read one XML and write two Excel sheets (parent items in 1st sheet, children items in the 2nd one). As I am new in this Pentaho tool I was missing `Block` node which you have mentioned above. Without it I have observed that two `Excel Writer` have tried to open for update the same file same time and as result two sheets were created, but one was empty. Plus additionally I need to have all my transformation in one single file. Hope it become more clear now. I will try your proposal on Monday and let you know if it works for me. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Just a comment: that you need to have all your transformations in a single file does not mean you cannot develop them in two (or more) separated files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pattern goes as follow:

- read data: 1 row per children, with the parent data in one or more column
- group the data : 1 row per parent, forget the children, keep the parent data. Transform and save as needed.
- back from the original data, lookup each row (children) and fetch the parent in the grouped data flow.
- the result is one row per children and the needed column of the transformed parent. Transform and save as needed.

It is a pattern, you may want to change the flow, and/or sort to speed up. But it will not lock, nor feed up the memory: the `group by` and `lookup` are pretty reliable.

[image]

Comment: Interesting pattern. I have managed to make it work without having issues with MS Excel. I have added solution transformation with suffix `-Answer` to the folder with question for all who is also interested to see it [here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1_KxHXLmguIE9ofnYT6aOsy926o7HhbhS). Still would be interesting to understand why `Block` node doesn't work as above pattern would be complex to apply in case of deeper XML structure when it is necessary to create separate Sheet for different level or there are more than one type of child node and all types have to land to own Sheets.

Answer (score 0):

Question 1: Yes, the step you are looking after is named `Block until this (other) step finishes`, or `Blocking Step (untill all rows are processed)`.

Question 2: Yes, you can pass the rows from one transformation to an other via the job. But it would be wiser to first produce the parent sheet and, when finished, read it again in the second transformation. You can also pass the row in a sub-transformation, or use other architecture strategies...

Question 3: (Short answer) The `Excel Writer` appends data (new sheet or new rows) to an existing Excel file, while the `Excel Output` creates and feed a one sheet Excel file.

Comment: Hi @AlainD. I have tried to put `Block` step in place. Unfortunately without success. I have updated my post with explanation why it doesn't work & put link to my files. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: There is a problem with Excel. You need to close the file before an other process can open it. Before you blame Pentaho, are you sure you did close your Excel on your terminal ? If yes, then I affraid you have to close the transformation (to close all open files), which mean to have a job to reopen to process the children.

Comment: I remove Excel between runs to make test clean & don't try to open it before transformation is finished. No blames, just trying to find a smooth solution which fit to my surrounding setup. Can be that I do something which have to be designed totally different. Still with my playground & it's flow I see that it can be some problem with releasing file resources. Have you tried to run my show case & reproduce the problem? I just curious if it happens on my machine or someone else can observe same behavior.